# Just installed Lazarus and my hello world doesn't show when I run project (ubuntu)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

This is what I've done so far:
Clicked on File > New > Project > Program

And this is the program:

```
program project1;
begin
writeln('hello');
readln;
end.
```

It compiles ok, I click on Run but it does nothing. It's like it's running but nothing shows up.

If I go to the folder where the program is saved there's an executable that works if I execute it from a terminal. Is that what im supposed to do everytime I want to run a program?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get tripped up by this, especially if you're used to running Windows.  The program below works fine for me on Ubuntu 14.04, but note the embedded comment.

```
program consoleapp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
  //  To see output use View > Debug Windows > Terminal Output
  writeln('hello world');
  readln;
end.
```